# AngularJS Modal (ui.bootstrap.modal) unable to trigger jQuery event after modal is opened (modalInstance.opened)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-bootstrap

I am using AngularUI Bootstrap modal dialog (example below). Once the template is opened I want to trigger some jQuery event. I am using modalInstance.opened method, but getting empty object.

**mycontroller.js**

```
var app = angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo');
 app.controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

  $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];
  $scope.open = function (size) {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
     templateUrl: 'mytemplate.html',
     controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
     size: size,
     resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        }
    }
   });

   modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
    // form submit. Works fine.
   });

   modalInstance.opened.then(function (selectedItem) {
    // I want to trigger jQuery event on form element
    // When I try to access $("form") I am getting empty object
   });
 }
});

app.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {
   $scope.form = {
     name : "Default Name"
     myItem : items[0]
   }
   $scope.ok = function () {
     $modalInstance.close($scope.form);
   };
});
```

**mytemplate.html**

```
<form>
  <label>Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" ng-bind="form.name" />
  ...
</form>
```

Comment: JSFiddle for anyone interested: http://jsfiddle.net/vugncsbt/1/
+1 This is a good question. However, if we know what you are doing, maybe we can suggest a workaround? Do you need the form just to fire a custom event from jQuery?

Comment: I have to do a jQuery form validation something like   `$("#myForm").validate(validationConfig)`. Since my application's validation is already written in jQuery I am bound to use jQuery validation rather than angularJS validation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think since the modal content is transcluded the open event fires but hasn't made that html available to the dom.

A simple timeout for 0s will move it behind the event.

```
   $timeout ( function(){
        console.log(angular.element("form"));
    },0);
```

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devitate/vugncsbt/4/)**

Comment: I am going with this solution. As soktinpk mentioned about adding custom directive `emit-event-when-loaded`, but I am wondering what is the use of modalInstance.opened method if we cannot achieve what it says in the doc. **opened - a promise that is resolved when a modal gets opened after downloading content's template and resolving all variables**

Comment: @user2300875 *downloading*, not necessarily rendering the content. It doesn't violate it's contract. The variables have to be resolved and the content has to be ready, but not necessarily appended to the DOM.

Comment: This worked, but remember to add $timeout as a dependency

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom directive `emit-event-when-loaded` and attach it to your form

Example:

```
app.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {
    $scope.form = {
        name: "Default Name",
        myItem: items[0]
    }
    $scope.ok = function () {
        $modalInstance.close($scope.form);
    };
}).directive("emitEventWhenLoaded", function() {
    return function() {
        console.log($("form")); // $("form") is defined
        angular.element("form").trigger("custom-event"); // do whatever you want
    }
});
```

Then in the HTML:

```
<form emit-event-when-loaded>
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" ng-bind="form.name" />
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vugncsbt/3/